# How can i display a tree view in my tableview cell?

Tags: ios, iphone, tree, tableview

This is my Original `value = "location_name": "Grogol, West"`. add to the Array.

**My Array is**

```
{
Ancol, North,
Grogol, West,
Kuningan, South,
Tanah Abang, Central,
Slipi, West,
Permata Hijau, South,
}
```

And in table data display look like that

```
1)north(Area)
   -Ancol(Location)
2)west
  -Grogol
  -Slipi
3)South
  -Kuningan
  -Permata Hijau
```

in this formate area and Location is define. I have seen Area wise location to the tableview.

[image: Look At the Picture.]

i want this in my table.

Comment: create variable `level` in your modal class and increase if the obj is children of someone else and then give leading constraint according to that(you can just multiply `constraint.constant` to `level`).  This is the approximately the approach I would have used. And if there is a limit of levels then you can make different cells for each level.

Comment: You don't need custom constraint - `UITableViewCell` has `indentationLevel` property which does exactly that.

Comment: its not about the constraint @NikhilManapure how can i impliment.